# Can I still write messages from @googlemail.com?

Tags: gmail

Some while back, Google changed all the user's email addresses to something like `nickname@gmail.com` (before that, for some users, it was `nickname@googlemail.com`). I can still receive messages to the `@googlemail` address, but cannot send ones.

This usually would not be a problem but I am kind of stuck on a mailing list and cannot unsubscribe, because the bot that manages the list does not recognize my `@gmail` address. Of course, I could contact the admin and let him remove me manually, but I would rather find out how to do it without bothering him.

Answer (score 1):

Go into **Settings > Accounts** and click on *Add another email address you own*.

[image: Settings > Accounts]

Enter the `googlemail.com` email address. (If your Gmail address is `nickname@gmail.com`, enter `nickname@googlemail.com`). Hit **Next Step »**.

[image: Add another email address you own step 1]

You will be alerted that a verification message needs to be sent. Confirm that the email address is correct, then hit **Send Verification**.

[image: Add another email address you own step 2]

An email message with a verification code will immediately wend its way to you. You can either copy-paste the verification code into this window or click the link in the email message. *Be careful!* When I tested this my verification message ended up in my Spam label.

[image: Add another email address you own - verification]

After you verify the address, you should now be able to use `nickname@googlemail.com` as the "From:" address of your email. If you prefer, you can also make it the default address (on Settings > Accounts).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can receive mail, you can go to `Settings` -> `Accounts` -> `Send mail as` and add your other email address. Gmail will send a verification email to that address to make sure you own it.